# Hide In[n] and Out[n] in Mathematica

Tags: mathematica, mathematica-notebook

Is it possible to hide the [CellLabels](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellLabel.html) `In[n]:=` and `Out[n]=` in a Mathematica notebook?
I don't want to hide the input or output, just the text `In[n]` and `Out[n]`.

Comment: This was also discussed a few times on [mathgroup](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup), e.g., [1](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/WqiawnDE7pw/discussion) [2](http://www.mathkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/symbolic-math/2168/Mathematica-How-to-turn-off-In-x-Out-x)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's an option "Show In/Out Names" in the preferences (Edit menu -> Preferences) under Evaluation.

It takes effect right away in the notebooks I already have open.

Comment: Not any more...

Answer (score 7):

### Method 0

The `In` and `Out` parts of the Mathematica notebook are automatically generated [CellLabels](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellLabel.html) for evaluated Input and generated Output cells. Since the numbering refers to the current kernel session, the labels are set to delete when you close the notebook (the cell styles have the option `CellLabelAutoDelete -> True`). So one solution is to close and then reopen the notebook before printing.

---

All of the following methods turn off **all** CellLabels, not just the In/Out ones.

### Method 1

(As mentioned in [rakslice's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/326784/hide-inn-and-outn-in-mathematica/326800#326800))
Use the "Show In/Out Names" toggle in the [preferences dialog](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/menuitem/Preferences.html). This sets the option `ShowCellLabel->False` globally, i.e. it turns off all CellLabels for all notebooks.

### Method 2

The option can also be set at a notebook, section or cell level (or globally) using the [option inspector](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OptionInspector.html).
For example, in the following screenshot I've turned off the cell labels for "Untitled 1" but left them on for "Untitled 2":
[image: screenshot]

### Method 3

You can also leave the [CellLabel](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellLabel.html) In/Out numbering in the notebook but turn it off when you print by changing a setting in the [stylesheet](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Stylesheets.html).

Go to Format > Edit Stylesheet. You'll get the blank, top-level stylesheet for the notebook you're working on. It inherits its styles from the "default.nb" stylesheet. Click on "Default.nb »" - it's a link, link and copy the `Style Environment Names` section to the stylesheet of the notebook. Select the cell bracket for the "Printout" environment cell and using the option inspector (Ctrl-Shift-O) (or by modifying the cell expression Ctrl-Shift-E) set the option `ShowCellLabel->False`.

[image: all steps in one image]

You could also create your own stylesheet to use in other notebooks or even change the default stylesheet to reflect your preferences.

Comment: +1 for a fine answer, informative and easy to follow.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Thanks! Shame about my mousewriting skills.

Comment: It's okay, I cannot afford a Wacom either. ;-)

Comment: Aaaand all images are gone, and the site prevented itself from archiving on archive.org :(

Answer (score 3):

Programmatically (IMO the fastest way to do it), use

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, ShowCellLabel -> False]
```

Doing it like this (or via the Option Inspector) is necessary starting in version 11.1.1, since the Evaluation preferences tab is gone.

You can also change it for just `$FrontEndSession` or `EvaluationNotebook[]`.